# Grouping in an SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables with schema as below:

**Please check sqlfiddle**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55fc2

Table: **Apps**

```
| ID (bigint) | USERID (Bigint)|      START_TIME (datetime) | 
-------------------------------------------------------------
|  1          |        13     |         2013-05-03 04:42:55 | 
|  2          |        13     |         2013-05-12 06:22:45 |
|  3          |        13     |         2013-06-12 08:44:24 |    
|  4          |        13     |         2013-06-24 04:20:56 |       
|  5          |        13     |         2013-06-26 08:20:26 |       
|  6          |        13     |         2013-09-12 05:48:27 |
```

Table: **Hosts**

```
| ID (bigint) | APPID (Bigint)|         DEVICE_ID (Bigint)  | 
-------------------------------------------------------------
|  1          |        1      |                           1 | 
|  2          |        2      |                           1 |
|  3          |        1      |                           1 |    
|  4          |        3      |                           3 |       
|  5          |        1      |                           4 |      
|  6          |        2      |                           3 |
```

Table:  **Usage**

```
| ID (bigint) | APPID (Bigint)|             HOSTID (Bigint) |   Factor (varchar)    |  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1          |        1      |                           1 |               Low     | 
|  2          |        1      |                           3 |               High    | 
|  3          |        2      |                           2 |               Low     | 
|  4          |        3      |                           4 |               Medium  | 
|  5          |        1      |                           5 |               Low     | 
|  6          |        2      |                           2 |               Medium  |
```

Now if put is userid, i want to get the **count of rows of table rows for each month (of all app) for each "Factor" month wise for the last 6 months**.

If a DEVICE_ID appears more than once in a month (based on START_TIME, based on joining Apps and Hosts), only the latest rows of Usage (based on combination of Apps, Hosts and Usage) be considered for calculating count.

**Example output of the query for the above example should be:** (for input user id=13)

```
| MONTH       | USAGE_COUNT   |               FACTOR        | 
-------------------------------------------------------------
|  5          |        0      |                 High        | 
|  6          |        0      |                 High        | 
|  7          |        0      |                 High        | 
|  8          |        0      |                 High        |       
|  9          |        0      |                 High        |       
|  10         |        0      |                 High        | 
|  5          |        2      |                 Low         | 
|  6          |        0      |                 Low         | 
|  7          |        0      |                 Low         | 
|  8          |        0      |                 Low         |       
|  9          |        0      |                 Low         |       
|  10         |        0      |                 Low         |
|  5          |        1      |                 Medium      | 
|  6          |        1      |                 Medium      | 
|  7          |        0      |                 Medium      | 
|  8          |        0      |                 Medium      |       
|  9          |        0      |                 Medium      |       
|  10         |        0      |                 Medium      |
```

**How is this calculated?**

1. For Month May 2013 (05-2013), there are two Apps from table Apps
2. In table Hosts , these apps are associated with device_id's 1,1,1,4,3
3. For this month (05-2013) for device_id=1, the latest value of start_time is:  2013-05-12 06:22:45 (from tables hosts,apps), so in table Usage, look for combination of appid=2&hostid=2 for which there are two rows one with factor Low and other Medium,
4. For this month (05-2013) for device_id=4, by following same procedure we get one entry i.e 0 Low
5. Similarly all the values are calculated.

To get the last 6 months via query i'm trying to get it with the following:

```
SELECT MONTH(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL aInt MONTH)) AS aMonth
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 0 AS aInt UNION SELECT -1 UNION SELECT -2 UNION SELECT -3 UNION SELECT -4 UNION SELECT -5
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the use of GROUP BY. Thats what you looking for. You can group your results into independent groups and use count and aggregation functions on those groups independently. Here is a [basic tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp).

Comment: Thank you. I have gone through a similar guide and tried for 2 days, but looks like this situation is too complex for me